# How do I read email headers from OWA with c#

Tags: c#, outlook-web-app

I just want to know How can I read headers from Outlook Web Application, I been searching but I cant find any solution for CSharp. please help.

thanks again

Comment: Please provide more context and background. Are you screenscraping OWA? Why not use Exchange Web Services instead?

Comment: Its just becouse I want to do a c# aplication using owa mail, this aplication will do many process after reading mail.

Comment: Automating Exchange via screenscraping OWA is not a supported scenario. Everything you'll want to do you can do via EWS instead.